# Custom ringtone for particular contact in 4.4.3

Tags: nexus-5, ringtone

I am using nexus 5 with 4.4.3. I tried to keep the custom ringtone for contacts. I am able to keep custom ringtone for a particular contact with no problem.

But when I choose `none`  (**ringtone with no sound** )from the list of ringtone available, when the particular contact calls the default ringtone is ringing rather than the `none` ringtone. How to keep `none` ringtone.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to fix this bug, so I used an MP3 of complete silence as the custom ringtone. You can follow the instructions for doing this here:http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127835/149206

Comment: Despite this working for a test contact I created, the contact I created for a spam number still had an audible ringtone the next time they called. I have now set that contact to go straight to voicemail. Hopefully, that will work.