# Set a custom ringtone on Sony Z3 Xperia Compact

Tags: ringtone, sony-xperia-z3-compact

I'm trying to set a custom ringtone on Sony Z3 Xperia Compact. I have copied the desired MP3 file into `/storage/emulated/0/Notifications`. However, on the ringtone list, I don't see the file and can't find any way to add it. There is no "Add" button in the ringtone list:

[image: ringtone list]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

There is only a "musical notes" icon button in the upper-right corner. If I press it, the following strange screen appears containing some unknown list of music without my ringtone:

[image: screen with unknown music]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

I have rebooted my phone and nothing changed. For some time after a reboot, I was unable to press the "musical notes" icon button since it was saying "Updating" or "Refreshing" in Russian. This was probably the media scanner running. So, I now know how to run the media scanner but still can't change my ringtone.

I have put the file into `/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones`. Also, I checked that it appeared in `/sdcard/Ringtones` and rebooted my phone, but nothing changed.

How can I set a custom ringtone on Sony Z3 Experia Compact?

Comment: Did you reboot after copying files? See if this helps: [Nexus 5x won't use custom ringtones/notifications](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126983)

Comment: Depending on how you've copied the `.mp3`, the Android system might not know about it yet (as the [media scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) didn't pick it up yet). Apart from that, it won't turn up as ringtone anyhow, as you've copied it to be a "notification sound" (see e.g. [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27740/16575)).

Comment: After the media scanner picked it up, it will show in the corresponding place. Which that is, depends on your "lucky choice". Make a good pick from the answer I've linked with my previous comment :) And what Firelord expected by a reboot: That's one of the events the media scanner gets triggered.

Comment: @Izzy I tried different folders. First one was `Ringtones`. What will happen if I guess the secret? How would I know that I guessed?

Comment: You've guessed the right folder. Did you reboot after placing the file there? And btw, ***how*** you've placed the file there (local via a file manager? remotely via MTP?) is an important point as to whether the media scanner was triggered immediately (it doesn't get triggered when doing it locally – but should get triggered when you close the MTP connection). But that nothing happened with your 2nd update confuses me: a few minutes after the boot (when the scanner has finished), the file should show up. Could you please add brand/model and Android version of your device?

Comment: @Izzy I put file with `ES File Manager` (don't know exact English name).

Comment: OK, that belongs to the "local placing". So you've chosen the correct directory now as far as I can tell, and did a reboot, waited a little to let the media scanner finish (cross-check: place some `.mp3` file somewhere else and see if it shows up in the audio player). Then it should be available to select from your first screenshot (in settings, where you configure it). If it doesn't, either the media scanner fails (hence the cross-check suggestion), or I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Izzy how it will be entitled there? By filename?

Comment: If it has no ID3 tag, then that would be the logical choice. Otherwise, it might well carry the ID3 title. Not sure, I've never checked into that (in my cases, the two usually matched).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Ringtones-to-an-Android-Phone), you need to put your files in `/storage/emulated/0/media/audio/ringtones`.

If it still doesn't work, try opening the file directly from an Android file explorer, then click "Set as ringtone" (you may need to click on the three dots before seeing it):

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Ringtone]

Comment: The folder `/storage/emulated/0/media/` is depicted by Facebook icon at mine. Inside it I have only `notfications` subfolder.

Comment: I know that Facebook put its notifications sound here. Probably why there's a Facebook icon. You can try manually creating the folder `/storage/emulated/0/media/audio/ringtones`. But since there's `/storage/emulated/0/media/notifications`, I would also try `/storage/emulated/0/media/ringtones`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play your audio file with the default music app.

Once the file is known in the music app, you will get an option to `Set as ringtone` if you select the file and click on the `…`

Answer (score 0):

In Android 9, any sound files stored in a folder named

```
Ringtones
```

*anywhere on the system* (`/media/ringtones` 
and `/Music/Ringtones` will both work)

will be found by the system and displayed as an option for a Ringtone sound

Any sound files stored in a folder named

```
Notifications
```

will be found by the system and displayed as an option for a Notification sound

You can also have more than one `Notifications` and `Ringtones` folders.